# How to block requests from apps like postman, insomnia and allow only one origin - django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I try to block the possibility to send a post request to my app via postman or insomnia. I want to limit the source of a request to one domain www.sample.com. I did add this domain to the ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, and nothing more and still I can send a request and save the data in my django app.

How can I limit the origin of a request to the one domain and block all others or return "Unauth msg"?

Stack: DJANGO REST Framework

I am able to add a check:

```
if not request.headers.__contains__("Origin") or request.headers["Origin"] not in HOSTS:
```

But I can fill the free field with key Origin and domain as a value in the postman app

Answer (score 4):

You cannot prevent a HTTP client from setting a header. If your API is available on Internet it is possible to send you any header. CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) rules are only applied in Web browsers.

Comment: So I can not prevent from sending requests from postman or receiving

Comment: @Marcin  If you want to secure your API you either have to have an Allow IP List and Block all other IP's, or you need to have some sort of authentication.   Authentication would be best, as even IP's can be spoofed.